# Programmatically reordering

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-community, programming, order-duplication

I'm trying to create a new order, based on an old order.

```
$orig_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load((int)$order_id);
        $order_model = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');

        try {
            $orig_order->setReordered(true); 
            $reorder = $order_model->initFromOrder($orig_order); 
            $reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals(); 
            $reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->save(); 
            $reorder->createOrder();
        } catch (Exception $e) {

        }
```

This doesn't do anything, but is the only reference I can find to programatically reordering. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have to recapture the payment information too?

Comment: Is the reordering option activated in your backend ?

Answer (score 4):

Theres information missing, however I will answer it using assumptions.

Using a clean install of Magento CE, I attempted to use the code above to recreate a existing complete order. Some of the assumptions I made are:

**Existing Completed Order**

- One product ordered
- Billing/Shipping address the same
- Payment Method: Check/Money Order
- Shipping Method: Flat rate

For simplicity, I created a file in my root with your code (yours would be in your extension). This file contained:

```
<?php
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$orderId= '1'; //You were missing the Order ID in your code (Issue #1)
$orig_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load((int)$orderId);
$order_model = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
try {
   $orig_order->setReordered(true);
   $reorder = $order_model->initFromOrder($orig_order);
   $reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->collectTotals();
   $reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->save();
   $reorder->createOrder();
} catch (Exception $e) {
}
```

When I ran this script, I didn't get an error message. However if you get the error message below, most likely you are using the wrong order ID (hint entity_id = order ID)

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/Sales/Order/Create.php on line 333

Speeding this up a little, I decided to rewrite the script, and soon after I started to get this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Varien_Exception' with message 'Invalid method Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Address::collectShippingRates

So I had to put some additional logic in here for shipping and I ended up with:

```
<?php
include_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$orderId= '1'; //Think of entity_id, not the preformatted ID of 1000000001
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$model = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/sales_order_create');
$order->setReordered(true);
$reorder = $model->initFromOrder($order);
//We needed additional logic for shipping rates
$reorder->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
        ->setShippingMethod($order->getShippingMethod())
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectShippingRates()
        ->collectTotals()
        ->save();
$reorder->createOrder();
```

I ran this two times and didn't see any errors. So I decided to go into the admin panel and look at my sales and I saw:

[image: Orders]

Comment: But above not copying order items, How can I do that?

Comment: I am sorry to asking your help in such a way here. Please can you guide me on this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266549/how-to-create-duplicate-new-quote-from-old-order-quote-magento-1-7